# How to check that (sub)string is a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript

There is lots of answers for that question on SO but none for javascript...

How can I check if first 16 characters of this sting `20130203003002od` is a number? Meaning that the substring doesn't contains any letters nor any other characters but digits?

Comment: Somebody suggested `isNaN(value)` function. But this comment was removed any idea why?

Comment: because the asker is only interested in finding if the first 16 characters contain only digits. `isNaN('0xf')`, for example will return `false` (meaning it is a number) and that isn't what the asker wanted since `x` and `f` aren't digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the string against a regular expression like so:

```
var data = "20130203003002od";
var matched = data.match("[0-9]{16}.*");
```

If matched is NULL, that means that the first 16 characters are not a number.

Comment: I like your answer. Thank you. Works nicely.

Answer (score 6):

> if first 16 characters ... [don't contain] any letters nor any other characters but digits

```
/^\d{16}/.test(str);
```

should work.